# DialogFlow Intent API - what do the object fields in the `intent.userSays` stand for?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm using the [Intents API in DialogFlow](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/intents) to create intents. I'm stuck on the `userSays` portion of the JSON body you send to the API.

I understand that these are user fields fields - but I'm not sure what the properties on these objects are. Specifically I'm looking at: `meta`, `count`, and `alias`. I don't know what these mean.

Here's the portion of the JSON body in particular:

```
"userSays": [
    {
      "count": 0,
      "data": [
        {
          "alias": "fruit",
          "meta": "@fruit",
          "text": "oranges",
          "userDefined": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "count": 0,
      "data": [
        {
          "text": "Add "
        },
        {
          "alias": "fruit",
          "meta": "@fruit",
          "text": "bananas",
          "userDefined": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "count": 0,
      "data": [
        {
          "text": "I need "
        },
        {
          "alias": "fruit",
          "meta": "@fruit",
          "text": "apples",
          "userDefined": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
```

I can't find any other documentation about these `userSays` objects in particular. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/intents#intent_json_object) that you linked to:

> Count
>
> > Equals to n-1 where n indicates how many times this example/template was added to this intent.
>
> Alias
>
> > This represents the "Parameter Name" in the parameter table.
>
> Meta
>
> > String starting with `@`
> > This represents the "Entity" in the parameter table.

Answer (score 2):

The objects in the userSays objects are used to identify the entities from the phrases which user might say.

```
{
      "count": 0,
      "data": [
        {
          "text": "I need "
        },
        {
          "alias": "fruit",
          "meta": "@fruit",
          "text": "apples",
          "userDefined": true
        }
      ]
}
```

This object will mean:
`I need apples` will be the user phrase in console.
`I need` is normal text
`apples` is the `entity`
`alias` is the `parameter` name i.e `fruit`
`meta` is the `entity name` i.e `fruit`
`entity fruit` contains values like **apples, bananas, oranges** etc

[image: fruit]

**EDIT:**
`Count` --> Equals to n-1 where n indicates how many times this example/template was added to this intent.